¿Por qué tengo este error Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 400 en Spring Boot?
Estoy aprendiendo con spring boot y estoy creando una app de reservas para un restaurante. Cuando envio los datos en el formulario para guardar la reserva obtengo este error Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 400.
Este es el formulario:
 
          
          
          
          
  
         
      
              
              
                  Número de comensales*
                  
                      
                          Abra este menú desplegable
                          Uno
                          Dos
                          Tres
                          Cuatro
                          Cinco
                      
                  
              
      
              
              
                  Fecha*
                  
                      
                  
              
      
              
              
                  Hora*
                  
                      
                  
              
      
              
              
                  Lugar*
                  
                      
                          Seleccione un lugar
                          Salón
                          Terraza
                      
                  
              
      
              
              
                  
                      Reservar
                  
              
          
      
Y este es método que registra al usuario:
 @PostMapping("/crear")
public RedirectView crearReserva(@ModelAttribute Reserva reserva, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String email = authentication.getName();
    AppUser appUser = userService.findByEmail(email);
    reserva.setAppUser(appUser);
    reservaService.guardarReserva(reserva);

    //Mensaje de éxito 
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "Reserva creada con éxito");

    //Redirigir a /reservas
    return new RedirectView("/reservas");
}

¿Podrían ayudarme a encontrar el error?

Código refactorizado
@PostMapping("/crear")
public RedirectView crearReserva(@ModelAttribute Reserva reserva, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String email = authentication.getName();
AppUser appUser = userService.findByEmail(email);
if (appUser != null) {
    reserva.setAppUser(appUser);
    reservaService.guardarReserva(reserva);

    // Mensaje de éxito
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "Reserva creada con éxito");

    // Redirigir a /reservas
    return new RedirectView("/reservas");
} else {
    // Manejar el caso en el que no se encuentre el usuario
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "Error al crear la reserva. Usuario no encontrado.");
    return new RedirectView("/error");
}

}
Explicación
En el código proporcionado, se ha realizado una refactorización para mejorar la gestión de la creación de reservas en la aplicación del restaurante. Se ha agregado una validación para asegurarse de que el usuario que realiza la reserva existe en el sistema antes de asignar la reserva a dicho usuario. Esto se logra verificando si el objeto appUser obtenido a partir del email del usuario no es nulo antes de continuar con el proceso de creación de la reserva.
Al realizar esta validación adicional, se evita un posible error al intentar asignar la reserva a un usuario inexistente, lo que podría estar causando el error de estado 400 que se estaba experimentando al enviar el formulario de reserva.
Además, se ha incluido un manejo de errores para el caso en el que no se encuentre el usuario en la base de datos. En este escenario, se agrega un mensaje de error a los atributos de redirección para informar al usuario sobre la situación y se redirige a una página de error para manejar adecuadamente esta condición inesperada.
Con estas modificaciones, se mejora la robustez y la claridad del código, asegurando un flujo más controlado y evitando posibles errores al crear reservas en la aplicación del restaurante.
